# RxJS module give error after update. how to solve?

Tags: import, rxjs, angular5, observable

In my angular 5 project. My imports have been producing weird errors that I cant remember having a few days ago. For the import here below it says: "module ...rxjs/observable has no exported member observable".

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

I did not have this before.

Funny thing is however, the angular website, including the functionality with the observable, works just fine

Here is my package.json:

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.2.2",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know how to solve the import problem. However, I think it might be worth mentioning that I experienced a similar issue when updating to the latest version for Angular 6, that is to say rxjs 6.3.0. So I downgraded to 6.2.1, which made the import errors go away.